# Powerbuilder - If value are null then account id on db table will change to 0

Tags: powerbuilder

currently i have a column ***profile.acct_no*** on datawindow, where user select a customer account from the popup listing. Now the problem is, user can't clear the previous already selected account, it always shows the selected account, unless you select another account. User can clear column box and click saved, but when they go back to view it, the account shows again.

Now from the database, all the selected account id are register into a table call ***interco.acct_id***, what i need to do is, code the event itemchanged where if the column ***profile.acct_no*** are null, then it will clear the account id from table ***interco.acct_id*** to 0.

What i already do is code the non-visual object business rule for the datawindow, at event ***ue_itemchanged_acct_no return none***:

***string   s_value***

***s_value = invo_tm.uf_getcolumnstring( istr_vldmsg.l_row, istr_vldmsg.s_column )***

***if isnull( s_value ) or trim( s_value ) = '' then***
***invo_tm.uf_setcolumn( istr_vldmsg.l_row, is_dirulealias + '.acct_id ', 0 )***

***end if***

Problem is, the account still shows and the id won't change to 0. Can anyone please help and advice? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would help you can attach a sample application or code. Without seeing what is actually written in the function uf_setcolumn and data window properties and event it would be harder to answer.

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to attach the sample application or code. Could you help? Thanks.

Comment: Upload your code on Google drive or similar online storage and post a link here.

Comment: I am not sure why '*user can't clear the previous already selected account*'. If it is because you get the message '`Item '' does not pass validation test`', then you can change that by clicking '`Empty string is NULL`' in the 'Edit' properties of the column.  Also make sure you have a call to 'AcceptText' before saving.  Otherwise, it is possible that the modifications are not accepted before proceeding to the save operation.

Comment: I've tried check 'Empty string is NULL' in the properties of the dw, but the modification still won't accept.

Comment: Is it a drop down datawindow? We often union an extra row to to clear selections. If my comment is off base- apologies- short in time today.

Answer (score 0):

I would check a few things.

- Check the update properties for your datawindow. interco.acct_id should be updateable.
- If **interco** and **profile** are both in the same datawindow, you will need to do some fancy footwork to update both tables. Check out this great article by *Rick Schultz* about *PFC DataWindow Multi-Table Update Service* here  https://pbbraindump.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/pfc-datawindow-multi-table-update-service/
- Also, if interco.acct_id or profile.acct_no are unique in the database then you will be unable to successfully change several records to 0.